# How to pass WcfRest url in update mode

Tags: wcf

Here i create a Simple wcf-Rest Service for Update with following methodes

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/UpdatexyzData",Method ="POST",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void Updatexyz(xyz Update);
```

When I try to Hit that Service from Browser I type Url  Like this

```
http://localhost:9706/EmployeeService.svc/UpdatexyzData
```

The Browser through an Error as Methode Not allowed Please Help me How to format the Url

Answer (score 0):

you created `POST` method. you cant access it with browser.
change the `Method ="GET"` or call it another way. you can use `Fiddler4`.

Comment: ur r8 but when  i try to hit from angular url its throughing An Error

Comment: dear @MdDastageerJob. you change the problem. please close this one and ask new question. and don't forgot to post the error detail so we can help you.